# Searching for Live Template in PhpStorm, from abbreviation (wrong expansion?)

Tags: phpstorm

In PhpStorm, inside of a blade-file (`some-view.blade.php`) when I write this:

```
@php
```

Then my code completion-box pops up and suggests this:

```
@php
@endphp
```

If I click <kbd>Enter</kbd> *or* <kbd>Tab</kbd>, then it expands to this:

```
pphp()
```

... Which I don't want. I don't know if this is a bug or what it is, but based on the code completion suggestions, I can't make out, why that is the result of this.

### Screenshots

HTML-expansion before (to show context)

[image: HTML expansion before, PhpStorm Live Templates]

When I hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, then it expands to this:

[image: HTML expansion after, PhpStorm live template]

But if I try to add a blade-tag, like this:

[image: PHP blade expansion before]

then if I press either <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it expands to this:

[image: PHP blade expansion after]

### Question 1 - Finding the live template

How do I find that live template that makes this expansion? I can't see it from the list of my 'Live Templates' in settings (see appendix 1 in the bottom).

### Question 2 - Make new-line without accepting the suggestion

When the code completion-box is open, how do I make a new line, without accepting the top-suggestions?

In other words: How do I only accept code completion suggestions with tab (and not enter)?

I tried looking at the [Code Completion documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/auto-completing-code.html#statements_completion), but I couldn't find the answer.
I obviously also looked around the settings in PhpStorm.

### Quickfix

As LazyOne pointed out in the comments, then a QuickFix is to remove the action from <kbd>Enter</kbd>, in the Keymap, for this action: `Editor Actions | Choose Lookup Item`.

I got that working and it's nice. But it's not the ideal solution, I'd say.

### Solution attempt: Search Live templates

[LazyOne linked to a way to search for Live Templates](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/4278782). But when I do that, I don't find anything:

[image: Search for live template]

---

### Appendix 1 - All live templates

[image: Live templates in settings, PhpStorm]

### Appendix 2 - Version and installed plugins

- I have the Blade-plugin installed (bundled with PhpStorm).
- PhpStorm version: 2022.1 (PS-221.5080.224, built on April 13, 2022)
- I'm on a MacBook Pro (2020)

---

### Answers to comments

**HTML Live templates**

Good point, about the context being HTML. Here are my HTML live templates:

[image: HTML live templates]

I did check them as well before the update of PhpStorm, and they didn't change - and doesn't explain the weird `pphp()`-thingy.

---

**Ctrl + Space**

I'm on a Mac.

- If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>, then the keyboard-toggler opens (OS-functionality).
- If I press <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>, then Spotlight (or Alfred) opens up (OS-functionality).

<s>I can't invoke this suggestion you're hinting at here.</s>

**UPDATE:** I got it working, by [disabling the MacOs-shortcut](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/308900/220328). But this shortcut gives me this:

[image: Basic Code completion]

How does this help me? :-)

---

**Ctrl+Enter and Shift+Enter**

While this is amazing! I was hoping to be able to change it so I never code complete with <kbd>Enter</kbd> (but always and only can do it with <kbd>Tab</kbd>). Since, when you're coding fastly, I don't want a new-line to be conditional to if PhpStorm suggests something or not. Can this be done?

---

**LazyOne's comment about what happens for her/him upon `@php` + Tab**

Thanks for the thorough testing! Maybe it's something in my setup. Hmm.

But are there a way, where I can search my Live Templates for, which of them have been invokes/used, so I can deactivate/delete them?

---

**Updated PhpStorm (this is where it gets weird!!)**

Okay... So I updated PhpStorm to version `2022.2.1`. When I opened PhpStorm again and tried writing `@php` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> and *hurray*, it expanded to...

```txt
@php

@endphp
```

So I wrote the comment you can see in the comment section.

HOWEVER!! PhpStorm was still indexing. And when it was finished indexing (which took a real long time, like 10-15 minutes), then `@php` + <kbd>Tab</kbd> was back to expanding to:

```txt
phpp()
```

So that must mean that this is somewhere in a file that is being indexed?!

Comment: **Q#1** Does not seem to come from PHP group (not a standard one). Plus, Blade file is not PHP context but HTML (PHP context is inside PHP tags only or places where PHP is injected (like a string in PHP's `eval()`). So check your other groups, might be there. The thing is -- the grouping is just for you to manage. What templates are applicable come from the actual Live Template context ("Applicable in" setting of the Live Template).

Comment: Try this: type `@php`, close completion popup, invoke completion popup manually (`Ctrl+Space` on most keymaps) -- what do you see then? Show a screenshot. If you have a Live Template it should be shown there (they have own symbol/icon).

Comment: I would also suggest to upgrade to 2022.2 -- it has certain improvements in Blade tags/stuff completion/priority (+ more will be in the next 2022.3).

Comment: **Q#2** You can just hit `Esc` to close the popup. Or use `Ctrl+Enter` or `Shift+Enter` to insert the new line (`Ctrl` will leave the caret as is while `Shift` will move it to the next line).

Comment: Back for **Q1**. If in 2022.1.4 I type `@php` and hit `Enter` while the completion popup is open I will get `@php()` (there will be only 2 entries there: `@php` and `@endphp`). But if I do `@php[Tab]`, it will insert `@<?php  ?>` for me -- that's my custom Live Template (`php` abbreviation). And if I invoke completion popup manually, it will be listed there and preselected.

Comment: Thanks for weighing in (as always, @LazyOne <3 ). I upgraded to `2022.2.1` and this weird `pphp()`-thing went away. So far so good. Now it expands to `@php` and `@endphp`. So if you post that suggestion in an answer, then I guess that is the core of the problem. I did add answers to your comments in the question, in case you have an answer to them as well. :)

Comment: *"I can't invoke this suggestion you're hinting at here."* Whatever you have got for `Code | Code Completion | Basic`

Comment: *"I was hoping to be able to change it so I never code complete with Enter (but always and only can do it with Tab)"* `Tab` and `Enter` in completion do **different things**. `Enter` just inserts the stuff while `Tab` replaces whatever is under the caret. This mainly applies when you are editing the existing code (e.g. changing the function name/editing the file path and alike)

Comment: `Settings/Preferences | Keymap` -- you can remove/replace the shortcuts for those actions. HINT: there is a button next to the local search field that finds actions by the assigned shortcut -- try it. Anyway: here on Windows `Tab` is assigned to `Editor Actions | Choose Lookup Item Replace` while `Enter` is for `Editor Actions | Choose Lookup Item`. You may just remove the shortcut from the last action (or from the first and assign it to the 2nd -- whatever works better to you).

Comment: *"But are there a way, where I can search my Live Templates for, which of them have been invokes/used"* The search in the Settings/Preferences works .. but only for the first match.. so not great. Fix your `Ctrl+Space` issue and you should see all suitable live templates in the completion popup. The just go through all groups looking by the name.  ANOTHER WAY: use `Code | Insert Live Template...` (`Ctrl+J` here) to invoke code completion with Live Templates only.

Comment: Missed this one. *"Good point, about the context being HTML. I did check them as well before the update of PhpStorm, and they didn't change - and doesn't explain the weird pphp()-thingy."* Just a note: The grouping is for convenience/management only. A user may accidentally create a live template for different context in another group (e.g. in Twig for example). It's the actual context of the live template itself that matters here.

Comment: Another use for groups is that all abbreviations within a group must be unique (even if they use different contexts). Check "PHP" and "PHP Interfaces" groups -- you will see they have the same named `pubf` and `pubsf` entries -- one used inside actual classes ("PHP" group -- got method bodies) and others are in interfaces only ("PHP Interfaces" group -- no method body)

Comment: Thanks for the further comments, @LazyOne . I added further findings in the question (especially the last bit about the update of PhpStorm confuses me). But I've also gotten `Ctrl` + `Space` to work (and added that to the question). I also removed the action from the `Enter`-key, that expands the suggestions. That's a nice quickfix.

Comment: *"then `@php` + `Tab` was back to expanding to: `phpp()`"* Since it's still an issue for you, please report it to PhpStorm Issue Tracker at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI

Comment: Just wondering: did you create a ticket on PhpStorm Issue Tracker as suggested? If you did -- can you post a link here?