# Disable code completion for a shortcut in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

I stumbled across this, when I tried solving this: [Searching for Live Template in PhpStorm, from abbreviation (wrong expansion?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73632504).

### TL;DR

In PhpStorm, in a markdown-file, when I write 3 back-ticks and press enter, it expands to this:

````
```angular2html

```
````

And I would like PhpStorm to stop helping me here, and just type what I typed:

````
```

```
````

### Detailed description and solution attempts

In a Markdown-file (`readme.md`), I use it often to write a code block with three ticks:

````
```
````

But when I do so, PhpStorm suggest a bunch of stuff:

[image: backtick expands in PhpStorm - angular2html]

So if I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> here, then it expands to:

````
```angular2html

```
````

So how do I change this behaviour?

---

#### Solution attempt 1: Deactivate the bundled Angular-plugin

There is a (bundled) plugin called: 'Angular and AngularJS'. If I deactivate that, then it looks like this:

[image: backtick expands in PhpStorm - apacheconf]

and expands to this:

````
```apacheconf

```
````

#### Solution attempt 2: Ensure Markdown is supported

I'm really baffled why this happens. Does PhpStorm not realize that I'm in an `.md`-file?
And/or is this the usual desired behaviour, when people write three backticks in a and `.md`-file?

I can confirm that I have an active (bundled) plugin called: 'Markdown' (version 222.3739.61).

#### Solution attempt 3: Add a new Live Template

This actually works, by making a new Live Template, to be this:

````
```
$END$
````

Remember the blank line underneath. This is since I would like to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and that replaces the first 3 ticks with this, but not the ones PhpStorm automatically adds dues to auto-closing of brackets and backticks.

This solution attempt seems quite hacky, though. :-/

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't/aren't just pressing `esc` key to close IntelliSense ?

Comment: Looks related: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-266239 -- the only related ticket I could find with my quick search.

Comment: @nbokmans - That as an option, yes. But I would like my IDE to work as smoothly as possible. So I don't have to jump through hoops, when writing stuff - or remember that I have to press `esc` before doing stuff, for it to write what I'm writing. 
And @LazyOne - Yep. That is exactly that. I'll "watch" that and weigh in with my findings there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-266239

> The pop up was created to make specification of code fence language easier and to enable automatic code injection. We can’t disable it since it would affect a lot of users using it for fast code injection.

`angular2html` is the first entry in your case. Somebody else may have another language ID (e.g. `aidl`).

Right now it cannot be disabled or customized. So you will have to either use your own workaround (with Live Template) or press <kbd>Esc</kbd> before hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Other than that: watch that [IDEA-266239 ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-266239) (star/vote/comment) to get notified with any progress. No better suggestions right now.